# chosen with bootstrap 3 not working properly

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-chosen

I have this code which triggers a bootstrap modal and load its content via `$.load()`. the page I'm loading has a select element which I'm calling chosen on.
Here's the code:

```
$('.someClick').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   x.modal('show');
   x.find('.modal-body').load('path/page.html',
function(response, status, xhr){

       if(status =="success")
        $("select[name=elementName]").chosen();

    });
});
```

the results I'm getting is like the following image:

[image: Modal View]

and this is my Html content:

```
 <select name="elementName" data-placeholder="Please work.." class="chosen-select">
        <option value="test">Hi</option>
        <option value="test2">bye</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: is there any JS console error like `chosen not found?`

Comment: @rt2800 - no, as you can see, chosen style is applied but the options are not loading / or its loaded but not displayed.!!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**Applying Chosen after the modal is shown should solve your problem:**

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $('.chosen-select', this).chosen();
});
```

**Or when Chosen was already applied, destroy and reapply:**

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $('.chosen-select', this).chosen('destroy').chosen();
});
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/koenpunt/W6dZV/

**So in your case it would probably something like:**

```
$('.someClick').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   x.modal('show');
   x.on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
       x.find('.modal-body').load('path/page.html', function(response, status, xhr){
           if(status == "success"){
               $("select[name=elementName]").chosen();
           }
       });
   });
});
```

---

**EDIT**

To complement Chosen you can use the [Chosen Bootstrap theme](https://gist.github.com/koenpunt/6424137)

Comment: I think you have a point here, I will try it and let you know.
even that I thought I was applying chosen after the modal is shown by using the success logic on load method. I still think your idea of using `on` method to check the modal will be much better than modifying the core.
+1 for now and I'll change the accepted answer once I check it ;)

Comment: This solved the problem but initially flashes the original bare html. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19089337/chosen-with-bootstrap-3-not-working-properly#comment67337057_25943654) fixed it for me.

Answer (score 20):

Try this, I  digged in chosen and found out that just need to pass options with "width" property like in this, or any other width value:

```
$("select").chosen({width: "inherit"})
```

Comment: this worked perfect for me, thanks, however I used

    $(".chosen").chosen({width: "inherit"});

Comment: `inherit` for me tries to inherit the width of each letter typed for the first word, creating thin vertical dropdowns dynamically. `100%` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 10):

As described in [Allow Chosen to be used in Bootstrap modal](https://github.com/Sikwan/chosen/commit/21a53f4aeb250d00af4ee401fbc3b30c19bb8daf), the problem is within the `chosen.jquery.js` file. I found it on line **435** and just added the following code inside the `else` statement.
check it out, it worked for me.

```
// Fixing problem when the select is not displayed.
   if ( this.form_field.offsetWidth == 0 ) {
      return "" + $(this.form_field).width() + "px";
    }
```

Comment: Ok, exactly what I wanted. Thanks :D

Comment: Modifying the source is not a real solution as this creates problems when upgrading..

Answer (score 3):

Adding width to your chosen class will solve this problem.

```
$('.someClick').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   x.modal('show');
   x.on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
       x.find('.modal-body').load('path/page.html', function(response, status, xhr){
           if(status == "success"){
               $("select[name=elementName]").chosen({ width:'100%' }); /* add width here !!! */
           }
       });
   });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem today but I needed a quickly solution... but firs a screenshot of my problem:

[This is my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UfpQ.png)

so I did this:

1) The problem is the "width", so I saw on console this

[take a look on the console, over the "select"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKdwN.png)

2) I made a quickly solution adding a new "width". As you can see in the previous image, there is a class 'class="chosen-container chosen-container-single', so I took the class "chosen-container" to add the new "width" when I call my "Modal". Here my code:

[just add one line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wc3x.png)

so, basically I added this code:

```
$('.chosen-container').css({ 'width':'350px' });
```

to the function that call the modal. Feel free to copy and paste this on your function :) Maybe it is not a perfect solution but it works for me and maybe for you too.

sorry for my english, but I'm learnig. I speak spanish better than english.
Greetings

PD: [There is my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaeTo.png)

Comment: `$('.chosen-container').css({ 'width':'100%' });` worked for me

Answer (score 1):

The following solution worked for me (from http://codepen.io/m-e-conroy/pen/ALsdF):

Redefine "modal" class:

```
.modal { 
    display: block;
}
```