# chosen select bootstrap shows twice in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap Select-box shows multiple times in bootstrap modal wizard. how to fix that? the image is shown below:

i have tried many things from stack questions but no use.

[image]

**My html/php part is below:**

```
<div class="wizard" id="satellite-wizard" data-title="Create Server">
    <div class="wizard-card wizard-card-overlay" data-cardname="location">
        <div class="wizard-input-section">
        <select name="location" data-placeholder="Monitor nodes" style="width:350px;" class="chzn-select">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option>Atlanta</option>
            <option selected>Chicago</option>
            <option>Dallas</option>
        </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS Code**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.fn.wizard.logging = true;
        var wizard = $('#satellite-wizard').wizard({
            keyboard : false,
            contentHeight : 400,
            contentWidth : 700,
            backdrop: 'static'
        });

        $(".chzn-select").chosen();

        wizard.on('closed', function() {
            wizard.reset();
        });

        $('#open-wizard').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            wizard.show();
        });
    });
```

Comment: That's a lot of JS code of which likely most is not relevant to the issue. Try removing parts of it successively, and see when/if the problem goes away, to narrow it down more.

Comment: Curious why you have a static width set to the chosen.js element? "style="width:350px;". Have you tried removing this and seeing if the doubling still happens?

Comment: @NathanielFlick after removing this it goes completely wrong.

Comment: Could do 100% instead?

Comment: @NathanielFlick tried it it nothing happened

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19089337/chosen-with-bootstrap-3-not-working-properly. Looks like you need to fire chosen after the modal is shown.

Answer (score 0):

When Bootstrap Select gets applied it actually creates a copy of your select and hides the original. If you are seeing 2 of your selects it's because the hide process failed. The usual trick to resolve this is to add this line (usually in the `done` callback of the Ajax request that populates the select)

`$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh')`